# How to count by two fields and join with other table Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have two tables, one table user and second table transactions related with the transactions done by a user. I want to do a query that give me the count by name and date, with the fields in user table. How can I do it?

```
Table user:

Name   Id Card
-----------------
Alex   01  N
James  02  Y


Table transaction:

Name   Date
-----------------
Alex   01/07/2012
Alex   01/12/2012
James  01/08/2012
Alex   01/07/2012
Alex   01/12/2012
James  01/07/2012
James  01/07/2012
```

I want sometihng like this:

```
Name   Date         Transactions    ID   Card
---------------------------------------------
Alex   01/07/2012   2               01   N
Alex   01/12/2012   2               01   N
James  01/08/2012   1               02   Y 
James  01/07/2012   2               02   Y
```

First of all I tryed to count by two columns with something like this:

```
select name, date, count(name, date) from pm_transaction GROUP BY (name,date)
select count(distinct(machine, date)) from pm_transaction
```

But it does not work, I tried a lot of combinations but no one works

Comment: What did you try so far? Please add your attempts and explain where you got stuck.

Comment: @diiN__________ added, I forgot, I still trying

Comment: GROUP BY the selected columns that are not arguments to aggregate functions. (I.e. Name, Date, ID andCard.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

`select tb1.name, tb2.date , tb2.transaction , tb1.Id, tb1.card 
 from tbUser as tb1 
 inner join 
 (select date,
  name,
  count(date) as transaction 
  from tbTransaction group by date) 
 as tb2 on tb1.name = tb2.name`

Comment: Transaction is always 1, I wold like to do the count by the two fields date and name. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Ur wellcome friend :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like simple aggregation task. Just check and correct table join condition and table names:

```
select u.name, t.date, count(1) as transactions, u.id, u.card
from transaction t
join user_table u on u.name = t.name
group by u.name, t.date, u.id, u.card;
```

Comment: sorry but, why count(1)?

Comment: count(1) works same as count(*) or count of any NOT NULL column. I use it for shorter code. If You use count(column), it will count only rows where this column is populated (not null).